# How do i have to standardize new incoming data to a trained model?

Tags: python, dataset, data-preprocessing, standardized

I have a trained model in python whose inputs are standarized arrays, following the formula ***(data_point-mean)/std***. Now I wish to test the network with new data:

- Let's say (just an example to understand the situation) my input data is a 2D array, and the first dimension has 2 different values: 100 or 200. I want to test if the model is able to predict the intermediate values between the two previous ones: 101,102,103,..., 199 (one unit increments) with a fixed second dimension value.

With this in mind, how do I should standardize this new "artificial" data? Do I add them to the real unstandardized dataset, standardize all together and then remove the new data and reserve it for testing? Or do I have to standardize them separately without the original data?

Thanks.

Comment: This needs more context. "A trained model" - what is this referring to? How is it represented, what libraries are you using, and how is it trained?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel sure sorry. I've trained a Gaussian Proccess Regressor to fit a dataset made of examples with 8 parameters, trying to predict a single numeric value. I'm using sklearn for the model, and pandas and numpy for the dataset. The 8 parameters are numeric ones also from [50,12000] with roughly 100 steps.